# Collect multiple nodes by an ancestor node value

Tags: css, ruby, xpath, nodes, nokogiri

I have one more question to handle nodes with nokogiri in Ruby and its multiple children nodes. I have the following code:

```
cpl.css("Segment").each do |u|
  segment_list_uuid = u.css("Id").first.text.gsub(/\n/,"")
  sequence_list_uuid_arr = Array.new
    u.xpath("//SequenceList[//*[starts-with(name(),'Sequence')]]").each do |s| 
      sequence_list_uuid = s.css("TrackId").first.text#.gsub(/\n/,"")
      sequence_list_uuid_arr.push(cpl_sequence_list_uuid) 
        #following some resource nodes 
        s.css("Resource").each do |f| 
          A = f.css("A").text.gsub(/\n/,"") 
          B = f.css("B").text.gsub(/\n/,"") 
          some_other = f.css("some_other").text.gsub(/\s+/, "\/") 
          #some more code 
       end #resource 
    end #sequence list 
  end #segment
```

There are multiple Segments with one SequenceList per Segment. Each segment could have multiple Resources. I have to collect the different resources in condition with the sequence lists "TrackId ". The informations found in each resource package will be used and checked by an following method. How could I improve my code? The following structure is given:

```
<SegmL>
  <Segment>
    <Id>UUID</Id>
      <Name>name_01</Name>
      <SeqList>
        <FirstSequence>
          <Id>UUID</Id>
          <TrackId>UUID</TrackId>
          <ResourceList>
            <Resource>
              <A>aaa</A>
              <B>bbb</B>
              <C>ccc</C>
              <D>ddd</D>
           </Resource>
           <Resource>
              <A>aaa</A>
              <B>bbb</B>
              <C>ccc</C>
              <D>ddd</D>
           </Resource>
        </ResourceList>
    </FirstSequence>
    <SecondSequence>
      <Id>UUID</Id>
      <TrackId>UUID</TrackId >
      <ResourceList> 
        <Resource> 
          <A>aaa</A>
          <B>bbb</B>
          <C>ccc</C> 
          <D>ddd</D>  
        </Resource>
        <Resource>
              <A>aaa</A>
              <B>bbb</B>
              <C>ccc</C>
              <D>ddd</D>
           </Resource>
      </ResourceList> 
    </SecondSequence>
  </SequList>
</Segment>
```

**Update 2016/04/11**

Sorry for that.

My problem is, that I need something like a package of all resources underneath the sequence list ancestor node. I have to calculate a value of each resource. After that step I have to add the two (or more) resources. The result is the new value for the complete sequence. But when I use my version of the code, I receive each single resource for the sequence. I hope my question is more clear.

**Update 2016/07/11**

My target output should be following:

I want to loop through the sequence list nodes on each resource. Then I want to collect all resource parameters, checking for some conditions and calculate one new value. After that I have to push each new calculated value from each resource in an array. In the end I check the content of the array for unique values.

Loop each segment for each sequence list. Loop the sequence list.

-> Loop resource 1 in the sequence list. Check if A exists. If not set B for A. Multiply A by C. Push new value to sequence_array.

-> Loop resource 2 in the sequence list. Check if A exists. If not set B for A. Multiply A by C. Push new value to sequence_array.

End of sequence list loop.

sequence_array:
Resource1 (AxC)
Resource2 (AxC)
ResourceX (AxC)

-> Checking for unique values in the sequence_array. If unique values found, push message to an XML by a defined method.

The sequence_list_uuids also added to a separate array and saved.

Thank you very much for your help and support!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the question is. Just a note : `string.gsub(/\n/,"") ` can be written `string.strip` if the newline is a the end of the string.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not give you all informations. I edited my question.

Comment: And thanks for the alternative shortened code!

Comment: I want to help, but I do not understand what you want. Can you please edit with a simple set of output that you would like, given the XML input?

Comment: I add my target output. Sorry for the layout, but at the moment I can't set any other layout, don't know the issue